# place autocomplete, google map javascript api vs google places api

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

`Google map javascript api`: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete

`Google places api`: https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete

They both offer seemingly the same feature, autocomplete.

Since, I am developing an webapp, I can use both, and I can't see much difference.
What are the significant differences between the two?

-- edit

There is also `google maps embeded api (webservice)`.
How is it conceptually differ or fit in with the above two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One is part of the javascript API, the other is a web service, intended for use server side